# Please provide an option to expand large chat messages in the transcript

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

During chat, there is a rare occasion that one might see an exceptionally large chat message. To stop it from consuming everything, chat politely cuts it down and gives you a link to see the full text.

You can't do this through the transcript. At best, you can check the history, but this [doesn't really cut the bill](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/310121/history): the "current state" will still be truncated, and the "old state" will have lost all of the formatting.

Can we have the ability to expand a truncated message in the transcript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There ya go :)
[image]

Comment: Excellent! Tested just now, and it works very smoothly. Thank you much!

Comment: You're da man @balpha!